# Suspend a device in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am thinking of suspending a particular platform device driver, while keeping rest of the system active.

1. Can this selective suspend be achieved by Linux Power Management? Or
2. Can I write a separate driver that can do this for me, by calling suspend directly on the platform device driver?

Comment: Did you check out the various files for the device in `sysfs` (often mounted as /sys)? They provide for per-device power control. A lot depends on how the device connects to the computer.

Comment: Yes, I looked at them and seems like runtime power management might answer my question. But can you elaborate on how does it depend on how device connects to the computer?

Comment: Because not all busses support powering down a device, nor do they all use the same way to do so

Answer (score 0):

For hard disks you can try [hdparm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) command for set hard disk in standby. The option you might be looking for is **-S**.

According linux man pages:

> Put the drive into idle (low-power) mode, and also set the standby (spindown) timeout for the drive. This timeout value is used by the drive to determine how long to wait (with no disk activity) before turning off the spindle motor to save power.